# RegExp with fixed text and space

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with a regexp in a java validation.

RegExp: "Office Boss|Standard Employee"
The string I am trying to validate with the expression is "Office Boss" for example, and when I use "matches" function it always return "false".

I am pretty sure it is for the white space, but how can I solve it?
I want to validate if the text is one of the two values in the expression only.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code exactly?

Comment: [Your regex works](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyu9rnfnr) with `matches()` and `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your expression in parentheses.

```
Pattern.compile("(Office Boss|Standard Employee)");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call find() before accessing your matched groups.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Office Boss|Standard Employee");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Office Boss");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

Comment: If OP did not use `find()` the result would be an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`, but OP gets `false` as a result